# What would be the best way to manage cloud credentials as part of an Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are going to be creating build/deploy pipelines in Azure DevOps to provision infrastructure in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using Terraform.  In order to execute  the Terraform provisioning script, we have to provide the GCP credentials so it can connect to our GCP account.  I have a credential file (JSON) that can be referenced in the Terraform script.  However, being new to build/deploy pipelines, I'm not clear on exactly what to do with the credential file.  That is something we don't want to hard-code in the TF script and we don't want to make it generally available to just anybody that has access to the TF scripts.  Where exactly would I put the credential file to secure it from prying eyes while making it available to the build pipeline?  Would I put it on an actual build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use build variables or store variables in key vault and pull those at deployment time. storing secrets on the build agent is worse, because that means you are locked in to this build agent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch